# Bring up a board

Tags: terminology

I often wince when I hear engineers at my current workplace say

*"We need to do xxx during the bring-up of the board."*

Basically, it is a board with a few components and as they test that the components are working, they are adding more or correct something, until they get a fully working board.  Is there a better term for that than "bring-up"?  Sometimes they use *"during the bringing-up process"*.

Comment: "Bring-up" is the common English term. "Debugging" might also be used, in analogy to the software process. More formally might be just some manner of "testing".

Comment: Can you explain more why you wince at the mention of that term? You may be able to refer to the process as DVT (design validation and test). Although maybe DVT and bring up are not really the same thing. It would just be a work-around to save you from wincing.

Comment: "Bring-up" or even "bringup" is the term used for exactly the process you describe by all hardware teams I've worked with.

Comment: Coming from a software background, I'm just not used to hearing a double-barreled word in that context.  Takes a lot of getting used to.

Comment: I don't think another phrase is needed - 'bring up the board' has been there in my start in the mid-80s and works great. Sounds like it's just a personal dislike you have for it. I don't know if 'bring up' is taken from the context of to bring up your children. (Americans use the phrase 'raise your children' instead, dunno about other countries. Sometimes non-US countries get phrases from US films.)

Comment: For major projects, I learned not to publicize the time of the bring-up. Otherwise, you may have a bunch of managers breathing down your neck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of 'bring up' has a long history. For instance the Oxford English Dictionary (paywalled, sorry) gives as meaning #2, first used in 1484

> To rear from childhood; to educate, breed.

and as meaning #1, first used in 1297

> To bring into a higher position; to elevate, raise,

and as meaning #9, first used 1823

> To develop, produce.

As a developer, I certainly think of my new boards as children. Flashing a single LED is often its 'first cry' (or maybe 'first steps', getting born successfully is not giving off smoke when power is first applied). It's no surprise that many developers use the phrase metaphorically to describe the process.

Any group of people will have their own language, or jargon. It can seem strange at first, until you get used to it. I'm sure I've heard software people talking about a server being 'up' or 'down'.

Regardless of how reasonable its etymology is, it's now an established phrase. By all means use an alternative phrase for the process if you like, but to kick back against others using it will not win you any friends.

Comment: I've always pictured it as necromancy! child rearing works too!

Answer (score 5):

"Bring-up" is indeed the proper term. It's different from testing or debugging.

Unlike software, hardware can self-destruct. For example, it can be wise to put a jumper between the switching regulator and the rest of the board. That way, if the regulator gets a bit cranky during its first power-up due to a design mistake and it outputs a very wrong voltage, the rest of the components won't smoke. Or you could slowly increase the current limit on the bench power supply, that kind of stuff.

Once it has been brought up and everything looks normal, then it can be tested to check if it works, then meets the design specifications, and debugged when it does not.

Basically, bring-up is a phase where you're concerned about stuff smoking. Testing is a phase where you're concerned about stuff not behaving exactly the way you want. It's important to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual origin or etymology of the phrase 'to bring up a board'. I'm not sure anyone does definitively.

But it's intended to be like bringing a new engine up to full speed ("bring the speed up", "bring it up to speed" etc.). Meaning doing it slowly and carefully, on the look-out for any breakages or signs of faults and failures, like parts going pop or feeling unexpectedly hot.

With a new board, you'd normally bring it up by loading it lightly or not at all, powering it (clicked straight on, or by slowly increasing the supply voltage) and then slowly using more features, loading more outputs and so on.

I don't think another phrase is needed - 'bring up the board' has been there in my start in the mid-80s and works great. Sounds like it's just a personal dislike you have for it, which is a harmless and natural-enough thing.

One of the first things I built professionally was a switch-mode power supply. That put rectified 240 V mains (about 340 V nom.) across electrolytic capacitors and you wouldn't want to be leaning over those if they went bang. So I very-much brought up the board rather than just switched it on. I was slowly winding the mains voltage up with a variac, from a distance away behind a table :-)

Comment: Haven't heard or bringing up an engine before - then again, I don't work in those circles.  Getting used to the term after hearing it every day, several times a day.  It is like equipments.  Takes a lot of getting used to.

Comment: @cup, you've never heard the phrase "bring the speed up" ? Not once, even in films, daily life, people driving cars or on bikes etc. :-)

Comment: I don't listen that carefully - I remember "bring up the speed" on standalone pumps/generators but I don't recall hearing "bring the speed up".  When driving/cycling, it is normally "can you drive/cycle faster/slower".  Maybe I'm in a country where people just phrase things differently.  I understand what you are saying: just don't recall ever hearing it phrased like that.

Comment: @cup, sure...which country are you in, by the way? "bring X up to speed" is probably more common. But, like you say, maybe it depends a lot on where you are and who you are. Like 'any road up', meaning 'anyway' or 'in any event', which is everyday common in the north of England but probably not abroad. Any road up, now you know :-D

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing the term, but for most of my career I've been a fairly independent design engineer, and then self-employed for over 30 years. I usually refer to the process as initial power-up and testing. Many of my designs had been high current primary injection circuit breaker test sets that typically were powered from a 480 VAC 400A mains circuit, and after a few exciting events, we used a current-limited variable voltage box to make sure there would be no nasty surprises.